# Writing image to specific folder using OutputStream in java

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i wanted to write uploaded image to some folder, but hear for the first try i thought to write it to the same path which i get by using " request.getRealPath("") " , after executing  the program flow went smoothly with out any error but i not able to find the image where it wrote...!. When i checked by debugging the program i come to know some odd path which i not able to find i.e

" /home/Software/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/elibrary/roronoa-zoro-wallpapers.jpg  "

i able to find only "/home/Software/workspace/ " and "last => /elibrary/" is my project name.

Currently i am using Spring mvc 3.2

this is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/catalogue/catalogueImageUpload.action",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public  void getimportedImage(USerDetails uploadItem,HttpServletRequest request) {

        try {

            MultipartFile file = uploadItem.getFileData();

            String fileName = null;

            InputStream inputStream = null;

            OutputStream outputStream = null;

            inputStream = file.getInputStream();

            fileName = request.getRealPath("") + file.getOriginalFilename();

            System.out.println(request.getRealPath("") + file.getOriginalFilename());

            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file.getOriginalFilename());

            int readBytes = 0;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[40000];


            while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) != -1) {

                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);

            }

            outputStream.close();

            inputStream.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

what i wanted ...?

=> i wanted to write image in specific folder which i able to find, it might be in project work space , or any of the drive , or with in the project with some folder say image folder

Comment: Have you set your OS to show hidden folders?

Comment: ya i did now i removed request.getRealPath("") and now i able to find image in eclipse folder how can i write image inside project only

Answer (score 0):

Ok...here goes.

- getimportedImage is not according to standard naming conventions, it should be getImportedImage
- You open a file stream for writing but do not try/finally the closing of it. If your code should fail, it could leave a file locked. (same for inputstream btw)
- On *nix systems files/folders with a leading "." in the name are hidden by default. You can either type in the full name of the path in the location bar of your file explorer or you can enable hidden files (in nautilus press ctrl+H)
- You should **not** depend on the path of the uploaded file, for all you know it could be /tmp which is automatically cleared by *nix systems. You should configure (possibly with a proper default) a path to use.
- Why is your buffer 40000 bytes big but you only read 10000 at a time?

...